# parseInt() error: invalid argument

Tags: javascript

I get a javascript error "invalid arguement" when I use parseInt(). What am i doing wrong?

The function is to increase the font size of every element on a frame by 1

```
<script>
   var sizeCounter = 1;
    function changeFontSize(){
        //var elements = parent.main.document.getElementsByTagName
        var myElements = parent.main.document.getElementsByTagName('*')

        for (i=0;i<myElements.length;i++){
                if(myElements[i].style.fontSize != null){       
                        var elmFontSize = myElements[i].style.fontSize + "";
                        elmFontSize.replace("px","");

                        if(elmFontSize != "") {
                            var elmFontSizeNum = parseInt(elmFontSize);

                        }
                            var resultSize = elmFontSizeNum + sizeCounter;

                            myElements[i].style.fontSize = resultSize + "px";


                        //alert(myElements[i].className)
                    }
                    sizeCounter++;
            }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `elmFontSize` before calling `parseInt()`? Try `console.log(elmFontSize)`.

Comment: This might not be related to the problem, but when you're using `replace`, you're not setting the result to anything: you need to use `elmFontSize=elmFontSize.replace("px","");` instead of `elmFontSize.replace("px","");`.

Comment: try to alert **elmFontSize** before you parseInt and check the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong. Here's a suggestion for simplifying/rewriting your function:

```
function changeFontSize(sizeCounter){
 sizeCounter = sizeCounter || 1;
 var myElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), currentFontSize = 0;
 for (i=0;i<myElements.length;i++){
  var fsNow = getStyle(myElements[i],'font-size');
  if (fsNow){
   currentFontSize = Number(fsNow.replace(/[^\d]/g,''));
   myElements[i].style.fontSize = (currentFontSize + sizeCounter) + 'px';
  }
 }
}
```

Where `getStyle` is:

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
  el = /string/i.test(typeof el) ? document.getElementById(el) : el;
  if (!el){return null;}
  var result;
  if (el.currentStyle){
    return el.currentStyle[styleProp];
  }
  else if (window.getComputedStyle){
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
           .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
  }
  return null;
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGpxU/)

Comment: it doesn't work. fsNow is always "undefined" i guess this is because the font size on my webpage(not mine) isnt explicitly set it uses css classes. style.fontSize returns an empty string for all the elements.

Comment: It should work. Here's a jsfiddle using the same functions, encapsulated in an object. This time there is no explicit font-size in any html-element. Click the button and see the fonts grow @ http://jsfiddle.net/aCqVZ/

Comment: Thanks for that. its working for firefox but not IE6 is there any tweaks that would make it work in IE6? also, the font only grows once is that what it should do?

Comment: In the newer jsfiddle, there's a limit defined for the growth. Regarding IE6: sorry, I will never write any line of code for IE6 anymore. That browser has taken enough time of my programming life, sorry. That said, here's code with comments you can use and/or fiddle with: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/r78Yr/

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` takes a string as first parameter, you may want to make sure that elmFontSize is actually a string using `typeof(elmFontSize)`. If it's not a string, you can transform it into a string before calling the `parseInt` function.

Answer (score 0):

You only handle "px" and fontsize isn't necessarily a "px" value.  If it is for example "em" then parseInt will fail because it is trying to convert a non number value.

Comment: That's not correct. `parseInt` can handle strings like `20em` in every single browser I have access to (Chrome, Safari, FF).